# Laravel Routes returning a 404 with route parameters

Tags: php, laravel, routes

This is not the first time that I have used route parameters in laravel, however I cannot seem to get this to work.

**Route:**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth|beta|admin'], function()
{
    Route::post('remove/{$id}', ['uses' => 'AdminController@postRemoveID', 'as' => 'admin.postremoveid']);
});
```

**Controller:**

```
public function postRemoveID($id)
 {
    $remove = ServiceProvider::where('id','=',$id)->first();
    $remove->delete();

    return Redirect::route('admin.manage'); //This just redirects to the page the user is currently on
 }
```

**Blade:**

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.postremoveid', $id) }}">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
</a>
```

What would be causing my site to be redirecting to a 404?

Thanks for all your help!!
-Patrick

Comment: You're waiting for a GET parameter in the controller, whereas the route responds to a POST request. If you want to use a POST request, get the `id` with `Input::get('id')` (cf. My Do answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Route:get();

```
  Route::get('remove/{id}', ['uses' => 'AdminController@getRemoveID', 'as' => 'admin.postremoveid']);
```

Controller:

```
public function getRemoveID($id)
 {
    $remove = ServiceProvider::where('id','=',$id)->first();
    $remove->delete();

    return Redirect::route('admin.manage'); //This just redirects to the page the user is currently on
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need that `$` on the wild card

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth|beta|admin'], function()
{
     Route::post('remove/{id}', ['uses' => 'AdminController@postRemoveID', 'as' => 'admin.postremoveid']);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This was one issue, but I was getting a methodnotaccepted error. My Do's answer solved this. Thanks again for the help!